# Google App Engine CardDav Example

Tags: google-app-engine, carddav

I am developing an application in Java using Google App engine. I have Google Contacts CardDAV API to access contacts.

How would I configure my project to access the contacts information. I googled but there isn't any proper guidance available for the same.

Help with example will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the CardDAV API specification in [this article](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/carddav/#specifications) on Google Developers. You simply need to interact with it like any other RESTful API, issuing commands like `GET, POST, DELETE`. You can easily issue these requests by using the HttpURLConnection class (documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)).